# Checking value of hundredths in Double

Tags: ios, swift, double, nsnumber

I have a number that is rounded to the nearest hundredth. I want to be able to check the value of the hundredths position. Is there an easy way to check a particular position in a Double in swift?

Example: 
If value is 123.07, I want to be able to find the value of the number in the position of 7.

So in Pseudo something like:
Double(123.07).hundredth == 7

Or would I have to do something like

```
var value = 123.07
value *= 10
//value is now 1230.7
value % 1
```

trying to make sure I do things the RIGHT way instead of the only way i know how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about it like this:

```
var value = 123.07;
var hundredth = ((value * 10) - floor(value * 10)) * 10; //floor rounds down
```

So, it becomes: (1230.70 - 1230.00) * 10 = 7.00

Remember, keep it simple!

Comment: This was a perfect drop in reply - which solved my problem, and was posted first.

Comment: @Charlie Great! I thought this was an appropriate answer, as it is not only easy, but also gives an idea of what actually happens.

Comment: Keeping it simple is the biggest struggle I have' thanks again :)

Comment: It won't give you 7, it will give you a Double value somewhere close to 7. Maybe bigger, maybe smaller, highly unlikely that it would be exactly 7.

Answer (score 4):

With `modf` function it can be made as simple as:

```
let hundredth = round(modf(value).1 * 100)
```

If you're going to use it often, you can create an extension:

```
extension Double {
    var hundredth: Int {
        return Int(round(modf(val).1 * 100))
    }
}
```

...And use it like this:

```
123.07.hundredth
```

Comment: I love the idea of making an extension for this, will have to try and get more comfortable doing this. Thank you for your reply, my gut says your answer is the most robust solution.

Comment: The `modf` function is **the** proper solution because of the quirky behavior of floating-point numbers.

Comment: To make your answer more "Swift" you can remove the `get{...}` and only use `var hundredth: Int { return ... }`